# Reassigning objects in Java with new

Tags: java

This is a noob question regarding memory allocation in Java.
I want to know if it is "problematic" to have the following reassignemnts:

For eg.

```
byte[] b = new byte[10];

..

b = new byte[20]

....

b = new byte[4]
```

Will this erase the stack and allocate new memory? Can we re-size the variable/object and re-dimension it this way?

Comment: @AbimaranKugathasan pretty much said it all, but what is your use case for this? Why would you want to resize your array? Lists might be more suitable.

Comment: One quick observation: those who contributed an answer by suggesting the use of `List<Byte>` should be well aware of how _space inefficient_ this solution is. This is why you hardly encounter it anywhere.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Will this erase the stack and allocate new memory?

Yes, older objects will be GCed if they don't have any live reference.

> Can we re-size the variable/object and re-dimension it this way?

No, Java arrays can't grow dynamically. Their size are always fixed.

If it's other object, you can change the state of the object. For Ex : `ArrayList`, You can change the size of a list after you create it.

> Probably just an additional question. If this is only allocating new
>   memory and the old one taken care of by GC, is it ok to do the
>   following:
>
> ```
> MyObject myobject = new MyObject(byte[20])
> ... 
> myobject= new MyObject(byte[10]);
> ```

Yes, It's perfectly correct. You are re assigning a new object to a older reference `myobject`.

Comment: Do mind the insertion cost of the various list implementations if you intend to resize often though.

Comment: Your words may be confusing for novice, the answer "Yes" on the question "Will this erase the stack..." is incorrect as there might be some code like `byte[] c = b;` in the `...` blocks

Comment: @ginz : I don't think, it will confuse in the context of posted code

Comment: Probably just an additional question. If this is only allocating new memory and the old one taken care of by GC, is it ok to do the following: MyObject myobject = new MyObject(byte[20])

...


myobject = new MyObject(byte[10]);

Comment: @user907810 : Answer updated with your latest question.

Answer (score 1):

Assigning a new object to variable will make previous object eligible for garbage collection if it is not referenced by any live thread.. and you can do like you have done.. and Assigning one object to another just assigns the object reference (a pointer more or less). It does NOT copy member variables etc.. e.g. b=c;

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this will allocate new memory, "erasing" the data in the original array.

If you want to resize the array, but keep the data in it, have a look at the Arrays.copyOf() methods and friends. That allows you to efficiently move data from one array to another:

```
int[] arr = new int[4];
arr = Arrays.copyOf(arr, 8); // Array is now 8 ints long, with the last 4 slots "empty"
```

Generally, if you want auto-resizing data structures, look at ArrayList, which is backed by a regular native array, but wraps it for you to handle automatic resizing.

Answer (score 0):

Any object we create using `new` will reside in the heap as long as there is a reference to that object.

in your case

```
byte[] b = new byte[10];  // new memory is created in heap

b = new byte[20] // new memory is created in heap
```

at this point your object in heap(`byte[10]` will be eligible for GC)

```
b = new byte[4] //new memory is created here
```

at this point your object in heap(`byte[20]` will be eligible for GC)

Arrays do not grow dynamically. `new` initializes a new array each time with new memory and old memory gets eligible for GC

Answer (score 0):

first one: Whenever you use new keyword it will always create new memory and previous ref. will be remove but it is not means that heap is clear actually it is the task assigned to GC and it will manage it very efficiently.

second one: you cannot resize an array but you can refer that data to another array which has new and larger size in that can un ref. object will be deleted by GC automatically.

third one:
arraylist can grow their size dynamically after their creation.

Answer (score 0):

No , once the new object has been created jvm automatically gc's the older ones . you cant find them in the stack.

As @Abiram explained you cant modify the state of Arrays . you could indeed try with ArrayList
for adding dynamic values . **If you don't explicitly initialize an instance variable, then that variable will still have its default initial value when new returns its reference.** Initial values are,

```
Type            Default Value
boolean         false
byte           (byte) 0
short          (short) 0
int 0
long             0L
char            \u0000
float           0.0f
double          0.0d
object reference    null
```

You can refer the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-5.html)
 here

Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 0):

> The `new` keyword will always creates a new instance independent of
>   the type specified.

**Will this erase the stack and allocate new memory?**

> Yes it will allocate a new memory for every `new`. And the old
>   location will be cleared when the next garbage collection is done and hence it
>   will clear the allocated space.

**Can we re-size the variable/object and re-dimension it this way?**

> No is my answer, you can't really create an byte array with dynamic
>   size. In fact, allocating too much memory to a single object will
>   create memory issues. So better fix some size based on the machine and
>   use the object wisely to avoid such issues.